# I cannot click on an element in appium

Tags: java, android, selenium, appium

```
xpath = "//hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.webkit.WebView/android.webkit.WebView/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View[1]/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View[3]/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View[2]/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View[3]/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View[1]/android.view.View"
```

I cannot click on this element or  tap it. Inside the appium inspector I was able to locate it and tap it, but when I run it on machine it won't tap or click says cannot find an element. Mobile Element has No text and resource id is dynamic always changes not stable.

Comment: Element you are trying to locate is inside a Webview. you need to switch context from Native to Webview. Are you switching context ?

Comment: No, I don't know how?

Comment: you can try using following function `public void changeContext(String reqContext) {
  Set<String> contextName = driver.getContextHandles();
  for (String contexts : contextName) {
      if (StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(contexts, reqContext)) {
          driver.context(contexts);
          break;
      }
  }
}` you need to pass the string e.g "webview" or "native" [link](http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/web/hybrid/)

Comment: You have to switch it inside the element? driver contains["WebView"]

Comment: Alex, actually there are 2 views in your App screen. Some elements are in 'Native' view while other are in 'Web' view. So if an element is in 'Web' view and you are trying to interact with that element without switching to 'Web' view then you won't be able to interact with that particular element. This applies to 'Native' view as well.